# Only one dynamically created picture box showing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to add multiple picture boxes depending on the length of a certain word. for example say it was six. That would mean i would need to create 6 picture boxes. Where it gets a bit trickier is the fact that i need these to stay centered. That is i need them picture boxes always to be centered all together like there are lined up in a horizontal row. I have a plan for that the only problem is that i can't seem to create more than one picturebox. This is my code so far.

```
    Dim dash(Len(correctWord) - 1) As PictureBox
    Dim count = 0
    Dim buffer = 55 * count
    While count <> Len(correctWord)
        dash(count) = New PictureBox
        dash(count).Image = My.Resources.dash
        dash(count).Visible = True
        dash(count).Width = 50
        dash(count).Height = 80
        dash(count).Top = 300
        If ((count Mod 2) = 0) Then
            dash(count).Left = (273 + (55 * buffer))
        Else
            dash(count).Left = (273 - (55 * buffer))
        End If
        Controls.Add(dash(count))
        count = count + 1
    End While
```

No matter how hard i try it only displays one picturebox. If anyone could be of assistance that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You add them all in the same location... you must change the top or left property in each iteration to see them all.

The problem is that `buffer` does not change it's value inside the while loop.
This should work:

```
Dim dash(Len(correctWord) - 1) As PictureBox
Dim count = 0
Dim buffer as integer
While count <> Len(correctWord)
    buffer = 55 * count
    dash(count) = New PictureBox
    dash(count).Image = My.Resources.dash
    dash(count).Visible = True
    dash(count).Width = 50
    dash(count).Height = 80
    dash(count).Top = 300
    If ((count Mod 2) = 0) Then
        dash(count).Left = (273 + buffer)
    Else
        dash(count).Left = (273 - buffer)
    End If
    Controls.Add(dash(count))
    count = count + 1
End While
```